# Dotnetnuke issue on certain pages

Tags: dotnetnuke, edit, setting

I have a website running on dotnetnuke. However, recently I can't do any action (edit content or page setting) on certain pages (the products subpges in www.midoco.com). Does anybody know why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

What version of DotNetNuke are you on? Check the HOST SETTINGS page to see if you are using the HOSTED Jquery option, if so, try disabling that option.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a javascript issue, try firing up chrome developer tools (hit F12 in chrome) and check if you have a red X in the bottom right corner. If so, click it and check what causes the issue. I had some similar issues caused by single quotes insted of apostrophes in a language pack and spent a lot of time to find the issue. I just went to one of the pages and see you have an error in /engine1/script.js in your skin.